# Transformed imageview isn't visible in viewgroup

Tags: android, layout, matrix, imageview, viewgroup

When I return transformed `ImageView` it shows on screen as it should.

While adding to layout it becomes not visible

I need to dynamically add a transformed `ImageView`s with a different absolute positions in layout

What kind of layout (or `ViewGroup`) do I need to use?

```
   ImageView iv = new ImageView(getActivity());
    iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    float[] values =
            {0.5f, 0, 139.35f,
                    0, 1, 373.75f,
                    0, 0, 1};
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setValues(values);
    iv.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    iv.setX(-100.5f);
    iv.setY(-32.5f);
    layout.addView(iv);

    return layout;
```

Comment: If you use setX/setY then why do you use a Matrix too?

Comment: I need to transform , scale,rotate it

Comment: when you senImageMatrix and then add your ImageView to the parent layout the Matrix will be reset by ImageView so you need to do that after it is set

Comment: you mean  to add image view to layout and then call SetImageMatrix()
like this?
I have tried this and it is not working.
ImageView iv = new ImageView(getActivity());
 layout.addView(iv);
iv.setImageMatrix(matrix);

Comment: Yes, i meanImageView

Comment: It still not working

Comment: Dear  pskink 
maybe I have done smith wrong,would you help me?

Comment: Set the matrix after the layout phase,  use for example ViewTreeObserver

Comment: Thanks for answering,but it still invisible,please give any advise
layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
iv = new ImageView(this);
layout.addView(iv);
iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
float[] values ={2, 0, 139.35f,0, 1, 373.75f, 0, 0, 1};
matrix.setValues(values);
ViewTreeObserver vto = layout.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
public void onGlobalLayout() {
iv.setImageMatrix(matrix);
//iv.setX(-100.5f);
//iv.setY(-32.5f);}});
setContentView(layout);

Comment: hmm, try iv.getVTO, not layout.getVTO

Comment: I have tried it but no result.

Comment: Maybe its to early,  try pre draw listener or for testing do it with some Handler delay

Comment: In such case it shows at the first moment without any transformation in the beginning of the screen and then disappears.I am struggling on this task for a long time I really need help